# How to prevent combination of i and j into a diagraph ij in PDF

Tags: symbols, pdf, miktex, font-encodings

I use the package `fontenc` to manage letters with diacritics as one glyph. However, the package `newtx` has the unpleasant side effect that it manages the combination of `i` and `j` as a glyph `ij`. This is very annoying if you copy text from a PDF file.

Is it possible to prevent the combination of `i` and `j`, a very common combination, to a diagraph `ij`?

I am using `pdflatex` in `MiKTeX`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for MiKTeX
\usepackage[osf]{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

demokracija

\end{document}
```

PS: Interestingly, ligatures are not a problem, because `ff`, `fi` and similar are copied from PDF as two letters, even though they were typed as single glyphs.

Comment: I thought that the problem had been solved, but it seems to have reappeared. I suspect a bad setting in the otf2tfm configuration.

Comment: I am sorry to post a duplicate, but I did not find the other answer because I was not searching for bijection :)

Comment: @egreg Where and how to report this issue?

Comment: You find the Michael Sharpe's address in the documentation.

Comment: hm `\pdfglyphtounicode{ij}{0069 006A}` should work, but I wonder why it is not there already. It looks like a standard glyph name. @egreg

Comment: @egreg ah I see from the duplicate that the problem is the ligature itself, but there's also the question how that should copy and paste.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there an advantage of using `\pdfglyphtounicode{ij}{0069 006A}` over `\DisableLigatures[I,i]{encoding=T1}`?

Comment: @egreg I am sorry, but there is no Michael Sharpe's address in `newtx` documentation.

Comment: @Pygmalion I filed a bug report.

Comment: depends what you want. If you want a ligature in print and ij when you copy&paste then \pdfglyphtounicode is the right thing, if you don't want a ligature in print then you need a different font or must disable the ligature.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I doubt that anyone notices the difference between ligature and no ligature in the case of `ij`, so this has no real effect. However, perhaps these two options lead to a different hyphenation, say `de-mo-kra-ci-ja` is an accepted way of hyphenating this word in Slavic languages. Does deactivating the ligature allow the `i-j` hyphenation?

Comment: @Pygmalion Michael Sharpe told me he pushed a new version fixing the issue.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the information.  Hopefully this propagates to MiKTeX soon.

Comment: @Pygmalion It has already found its way in TeX Live.

Comment: @egreg Today it came to MiKTeX too.